# How to Create an Arc that always opens to a fixed point

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a *sunflower effect* on canvas, with an arc, and my geometry skills are rusty.

To start, I created an origin point somewhere in the middle of the canvas, **Origin** (X1, Y1)
Then I create get the Mouse Position **Mp** (Xm, Ym)

Now if I make an imaginary line from **Origin** to **Mp**, then **Mp** should be the point that bisects the arc with a new smaller origin point which is in the direction of the **Origin**, that will define the arc with a static radius (say 20). All three points **Origin**, **Mp** and the smaller Radius should form a straight line.

I want it to cut through the centre of the arc with a static radius (say 20) regardless of how close of far the mouse is from Origin.

So, if you imagine a clock. If the middle part where the hands connect is **Origin**.

- If the mouse is at the 3 o'clock position the Arc looks like a ")"
- If the mouse is at the 9 o'clock position the Arc looks like a "("
- If the mouse is at the 12 o'clock position the Arc looks like a "(" if it were rotated 90°
- If the mouse is at the 6 o'clock position the Arc looks like a "(" if it were rotated 270°
- etc...

And the mouse is on top of that Arc.

For my question, specifically it's not so much the how to get points, or mouseevents or anything, but assuming I have {X1,Y1} and {Xm,Ym}, what is the math needed to make an arc as described above?

Or for the JS/jQuery experts, the arc() params?

**Edit**: a very poor photoshop render
[image: Curves]

The bottom right one has a mouse added to show generally where the mouse pointer is at the time the arc/curve is drawn.

Comment: I just realized I might have over thought this question. It might be easier to draw the small arc at **Mp** in one orientation and then rotate it... Still unsure if that makes it easier or harder though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The simplest way is to adjust the starting & ending angles of the arc command.**

You can draw a series of arc's to form your flower.

Hint: If you want your petals to be less round and more curved, you might use `quadraticCurveTo` instead of arcs to draw the outside of the petals.

Good luck with your project!

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=50;
var PI=Math.PI;
var startAngle=0-PI/8;
var sweepAngle=PI/4;
var nextTime=0;
var delay=250;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function draw(){

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,5,0,PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,startAngle+sweepAngle);
  ctx.stroke();

}

function animate(time){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(time>nextTime){
    draw();
    startAngle+=PI*2/30;
    nextTime+=delay;
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ Addition based on more information ]**

Yep, I think you've got it!

Start with the mouse position `mcx,mcy`.

Define an angle that a smaller circle centerpoint is versus the mouse position `radianAngle`.

Define how far that small centerpoint is away from the mouse centerpoint `radius`.

Calculate the centerpoint of the small circle:

```
var scx = mcx + radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
var scy = mcy + radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
```

Define the radius of the smaller circle `smallRadius`.

Define the total sweepAngle you want on the smaller arc `sweepAngle`.

Define the starting & ending angles of the arc on your small circle. This is actually easy because you want the small arc to "point" at the mouse point.  Hint: The center of the small arc must always be the at the midpoint of the `radianAngle`. Therefore, the `startingAngle` = `( radianAngle - sweepAngle/2`.

So finally your small angle that "points" to the mouse becomes:

```
ctx.arc( scx,scy, smallRadius, startingAngle, startingAngle+sweepAngle );
```

Cheers!

Comment: Very cool, and lots to digest, but the problem is slightly more complicated the petals are smaller circles that point to the centre.
So, rather than drawing a flower, I called it that because the mini arcs are like sunflowers that always look at the sun (middle point) while it moves across the sky.

Comment: I'm not understanding :-/ Circles don't really point anywhere(?). Could you do a mockup in Photoshop or your favorite image editor?

Comment: Added a render of sorts, but I think what I need to do is to take your idea of showing the start angle and end angle, to apply to the smaller curve to make it always 'point' at the origin point (do the math based on the big circle and apply it to the little circle). And then all I'll need to add is a way to figure out how to offset the centre point of the smaller circle in the direction of the centre point a distance of Radius away from the mouse, and hope for a reasonably close approximation.

Comment: @DaveGoten, I think you've got it! I added to my answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Adding** Just because:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var canvas = $('#canvas');

      function getPosition(mouseEvent) {
        var x, y;
        x = mouseEvent.clientX;
        y = mouseEvent.clientY;
        return {
          X: x - canvas.offset().left,
          Y: y - canvas.offset().top
        };
      }

      $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
        var origin = {
          x: 325,
          y: 100
        };
        var posit = getPosition(e)
        var degrees = Math.PI /
          180;
        var plotR = {
          X: 0,
          Y: 0
        };
        var radius = 15;
        var curveDeg = 65;
        var context = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');

        if (posit.X >= origin.x && posit.Y <= origin.y) {
          quadrant = 1;
        } else if (posit.X >= origin.x && posit.Y >= origin.y) {
          quadrant = 2;
        } else if (posit.X < origin.x && posit.Y >= origin.y) {
          quadrant = 3;
        } else {
          quadrant = 4;
        }

        deltaY = posit.Y - origin.y;
        deltaX = posit.X - origin.x;

        if (deltaX == 0) {
          distance = deltaY;
          plotR.X = origin.x;
          switch (quadrant) {
            case 2:
            case 3:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y - radius;
              break;
            case 1:
            case 4:
            default:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y + radius;
              break;
          }
        } else {
          distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));
          slope = deltaY / deltaX;
          delta = radius / (Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(slope, 2)));

          switch (quadrant) {
            case 1:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y - slope * delta;
              plotR.X = posit.X - delta;
              break;
            case 2:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y - slope * delta;
              plotR.X = posit.X - delta;
              break;
            case 3:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y + slope * delta;
              plotR.X = posit.X + delta;

              break;
            case 4:
            default:
              plotR.Y = posit.Y + slope * delta;
              plotR.X = posit.X + delta;
              break;
          }
        }
        startAngle = Math.acos(deltaX / distance);
        if (quadrant == 1 || quadrant == 4) startAngle = -startAngle;


        context.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 400);

        // Draw Origin Point for reference, but not for production
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
        context.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
        context.arc(origin.x, origin.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fill();

        // Drawn Calculated Origin point offset from Mouse in the direction of Origin Point
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
        context.strokeStyle = "#00FF00";
        context.arc(plotR.X, plotR.Y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fill();

        // Draw 'Sunflower' Curve
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
        context.arc(plotR.X, plotR.Y, radius, startAngle - (curveDeg * degrees / 2), startAngle + (curveDeg * degrees / 2), false);

        context.stroke();
        return;
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="200" style=" border: 1px #000 solid"></canvas>
```